# Android Animations and functions need to move to activity?

Tags: android, design-patterns, view, bluetooth

I am working on a small game with touch-motion, bluetooth, and menus. At the moment the code is implemented is in my custom View.

For example vectors of classes that store game-data, vectors for current data and later will there be some threads for animations and timers.
Yet there is no icons for "abilities", but I will implement them too.
Later will there be a process or a service with bluetooth which also calls methods which are at the moment in the custom view class.

I suppose this is a bad design - so I have no concrete idea how I can or should move my functions to for example the activity which holds the custom view and how to let the custom view and activity communicate with each other.
Maybe some of you have advice on what to do.

Here is the activity:

Gamecontroller_Activity:

```
public class Gamecontroller_Activity extends Activity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Enter Function","Enter onCreate Gamecontroler_Activity");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gamecontroller);
    }
}
```

activity_gamecontroller.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.calma.Gamecontroller_View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the big custom view class (shorted) Gamecontroller_View.java:

```
public class Gamecontroller_View  extends View implements OnGestureListener{
    

    //Touch
     private PointF fingerpointer;
     private int totalClickt;
     private static final int SIZE = 60;

     private Paint mPaint;
     
     //Text Flashes
     private Paint textPaint;
     private Paint textPaintAction;
     private String currentMsg;
     private boolean currentMsgShow;
     
     //Drawables (Pictures)
     private int monsterscale;
     private int monsterMinimumBorderX;
     private int monsterMinimumBorderY;
     private Bitmap bitmap1,bitmap2;
     private HashMap<String, Bitmap> hashmapMonsterStandartBitmap;
     
     Display Informations;
     private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
     private int xDisplayMaximum;
     private int yDisplayMaximum;
         
     //Monsters
     private Vector<Monster>  currentMonsters;
     private int monsterCountGlobal;
     
     //Player Stats
     private Player playerMe;
     
     //Enemy Player Stats
     private Player playerEnemy;
    
    public Gamecontroller_View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView();
      }
    
    
    public void initView(){
        
        //display

        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        
        float displayPixelFactor = displayMetrics.widthPixels/displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        xDisplayMaximum =  displayMetrics.widthPixels ;
        yDisplayMaximum =   displayMetrics.heightPixels - (3*getStatusBarSizes());


        Log.i("Display","displaywidthpixels/displayMetrics: "+xDisplayMaximum);
        //yDisplayMaximum 
        
        
        //Enemy Player
        playerEnemy = new Player();
        
        //Monsters
        monsterscale =10;
        monsterMinimumBorderX= Math.min(xDisplayMaximum,yDisplayMaximum)/monsterscale;
        monsterMinimumBorderY= Math.max(xDisplayMaximum,yDisplayMaximum)/monsterscale;
        hashmapMonsterStandartBitmap = new HashMap<String,Bitmap>();
        currentMonsters = new Vector<Monster>();
        monsterCountGlobal = 0;
        Log.i("display","Monsterscale: "+monsterscale + " minMonsterBorder: "+monsterMinimumBorderX);
        
        
        //init Touch detection and draw
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.OUTER));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
       
       //init Text wich will be drawn 
        textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint.setTextSize(30);
        textPaintAction = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaintAction.setTextSize(60);
        
        currentMsg = "";
        currentMsgShow = false;
        
        
        //Futher init stuff
        initPlayerMe();
        initPlayerEnemy();
        enemySpawn();
        preloadImages();
        showDebug();
        
    }
    
    public void initPlayerMe(){
        //Player
        playerMe = new Player();
        playerMe.setlife(100);
        playerMe.setMoney(0);
        playerMe.setStrength(1);
    
    }
    
    public void initPlayerEnemy(){
        //Player
        playerEnemy = new Player();
        playerEnemy.setlife(100);
        playerEnemy.setMoney(0);
        playerEnemy.setStrength(1);
    }
    
    public Vector<Dimension> findPlaceForMonsters(int n){
        
        //First Collect allready existing Monster Coordinates
        Vector <Dimension> currentPlaces = new Vector<Dimension>();
        Vector <Dimension> newPlaces = new Vector<Dimension>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i< currentMonsters.size();i++){
            if (currentMonsters.elementAt(i) != null){
                currentPlaces.add(currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getDimension());
                
            }
        }
        
        for (int i=0; i < n ;i++){
        newPlaces.add(new Dimension(getRandomNumberBetween(0, xDisplayMaximum-monsterMinimumBorderX),
                                    getRandomNumberBetween(0, yDisplayMaximum-monsterMinimumBorderY)));
        Log.i("randomPlaces","Point xy: " + newPlaces.lastElement().getX()+ " "+newPlaces.lastElement().getY());

        }
        
        Log.i("findPlfaceForMonsters",this.monsterMinimumBorderX+" "+this.monsterMinimumBorderY);
        
        return newPlaces;
    }
    
    public void enemySpawn(){
        
        int tempCount =0;

        Vector<Dimension> newPlaces = findPlaceForMonsters(6);

        
        for(int i=0; i < 2;i++){
            currentMonsters.add(new MonsterMedium(monsterCountGlobal));
            currentMonsters.lastElement().setDimension(new Dimension(newPlaces.elementAt(tempCount).getX(),newPlaces.elementAt(tempCount).getY(),monsterMinimumBorderX,monsterMinimumBorderY));
            monsterCountGlobal++;
            tempCount++;
        }   
        
        for(int i=0; i < 2;i++){
            currentMonsters.add(new MonsterSmall(monsterCountGlobal));
            currentMonsters.lastElement().setDimension(new Dimension(newPlaces.elementAt(tempCount).getX(),newPlaces.elementAt(tempCount).getY(),monsterMinimumBorderX,monsterMinimumBorderY));
            monsterCountGlobal++;
            tempCount++;

        }   
        for(int i=0; i < 2;i++){
            currentMonsters.add(new MonsterHeavy(monsterCountGlobal));
            currentMonsters.lastElement().setDimension(new Dimension(newPlaces.elementAt(tempCount).getX(),newPlaces.elementAt(tempCount).getY(),monsterMinimumBorderX,monsterMinimumBorderY));
            monsterCountGlobal++;
            tempCount++;
        }   
            
            
        

    }
    
    public void attackMonster(int id){
        
        for (int i=currentMonsters.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
            if (currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getID() == id){
            
                int restlife = currentMonsters.elementAt(i).setDamge(this.playerMe.getStrength());
                lifeOfMonsterChanged(currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getID(),i,restlife);
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public void lifeOfMonsterChanged(int id,int index, int life){
        if (life <= 0){
            Log.i("MonsterTouchted", "Monster tot");
            currentMonsters.removeElementAt(index);
        }
        else{
            Log.i("MonsterTouchted", "Monster "+id+" restlife: "+life);
            //effekte? (shake?) farbE?
        }
    }
       
    
    @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // get pointer index from the event object
        int pointerIndex = event.getActionIndex();

        // get pointer ID
        int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        Log.i("touch","event.getPointerID(): "+pointerId);


        // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
        int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (maskedAction) {

        //Detection of a finger touch
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            totalClickt = totalClickt+1;
            //attackTheMonster(currentPlayer.attack()); 
            fingerpointer = new PointF();
            fingerpointer.x = event.getX(0);
            fingerpointer.y = event.getY(0);
            
            for (int i=currentMonsters.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
                if(currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getDimension().contains((int)fingerpointer.x, (int)fingerpointer.y)){
                    Log.i("MonsterTouchted","MonsterTouched: index: "+i);
                    attackMonster(currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getID());
                    break;
                }
            }
    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: 
            {
          // Optional more than one finger

          break;
        }
        
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
        { // a pointer was moved
            if (fingerpointer != null) {
                fingerpointer.x = event.getX(0);
                fingerpointer.y = event.getY(0);
                }   
          break;
        }
        
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            fingerpointer = null;
        break;
        }
        }
        invalidate();

        return true;
      }



    
      @Override
      protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // draw all pointers
          if (fingerpointer != null){

          mPaint.setColor(colors[0]);
          canvas.drawCircle(fingerpointer.x, fingerpointer.y, SIZE, mPaint);
          }
        
        
        // draw mosnters

          
        for(int i=0; i < currentMonsters.size();i++){
            if( currentMonsters.elementAt(i) != null){
                                canvas.drawBitmap(hashmapMonsterStandartBitmap.get(currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getImagePath()), currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getDimension().getX(), currentMonsters.elementAt(i).getDimension().getY(), mPaint); //bitmap, abstand left, abstand top, paint
                
            } else{
                Log.i("Failure","Draw monster nullpointer bei index: "+i);
            }
        }
        
        //draw extra texts
        if(currentMsgShow){
        Log.i("onDraw","enter currenMsgShow");

            if(displayMetrics != null){
            int textsize =  (int) textPaintAction.measureText(currentMsg);
            int sidespacing = (displayMetrics.widthPixels - textsize)/2;
            canvas.drawText(currentMsg, sidespacing, displayMetrics.heightPixels/5 , textPaintAction);
            }
        }
        
        //Draw extratext
        canvas.drawText( "Total Clickt: " + totalClickt, 10, 40 , textPaint);
 }
}
```

Project:

[image: Project]

Comment: you want to call **Gamecontroller_View** methods inside **Gamecontroller_Activity**? is that your problem?

Comment: @ Rami yes - how to call them in my activity. And how to bring the data to the activity too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make those changes:

1) in your *activity_gamecontroller.xml*:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.calma.Gamecontroller_View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myGameController"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2) in your *Gamecontroller_Activity*:

```
public class Gamecontroller_Activity extends Activity {

    Gamecontroller_View mGameControllerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Enter Function","Enter onCreate Gamecontroler_Activity");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gamecontroller);
        mGameControllerView = (Gamecontroller_View) findViewById(R.id.myGameController);
    }
}
```

3) now you can call for example `mGameControllerView.initPlayerMe();` from any method in your *Gamecontroller_Activity* .

This is an example:

```
 public class Gamecontroller_Activity extends Activity {

        Gamecontroller_View mGameControllerView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.i("Enter Function","Enter onCreate Gamecontroler_Activity");
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_gamecontroller);
            mGameControllerView = (Gamecontroller_View) findViewById(R.id.myGameController);
            testMethod();
        }

        private void testMethod(){
            mGameControllerView.enemySpawn();
        } 
 }
```

Comment: thank you Rami. And the other way, when i know want to call methodes of the activity from the view?

Comment: You r welcome! --- There is no direct way to do it. Maybe you can use an interface for that.